# React doesn't render array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

my React code doesn't works. 
I've an array, and, for each item, I need to render a card. 
But it doesn't works.
This is all the code:

```js
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [servers, setServers] = useState({});

  async function getServers() {
    console.log('ready');

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/server/servers').then(
      (res) => res.json()
    );

    setServers(response);
    console.log(response);

    console.log('servers object updated: ' + JSON.stringify(servers));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getServers();
    import('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ['Karla:600', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('servers object updated: ' + JSON.stringify(servers));
  }, [servers]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row" style={{ color: 'white' }}>
          {servers.database?.map((server, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="col">
              <div
                className="card"
                style={{
                  width: '18rem',
                  backgroundColor: '#101114',
                  color: 'white',
                  marginTop: '80px',
                  borderRadius: '15px',
                  boxShadow: '4px 3px 5px 0px #7335fb',
                }}
              >
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/843104500713127946/a_91371d39bec9e454d0f4ccacbfaea9f8.gif?size=512"
                  className="card-img-top"
                  alt="Icona server"
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: '50%',
                    width: '96px',
                    marginLeft: '20px',
                    marginTop: '60px',
                  }}
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">
                    {servers.bot[index].name || 'Errore!'}
                  </h5>
                  <br />
                  <p className="card-text">{server.shortDescription}</p>
                  <br />
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="btn"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#5316d9', color: 'white' }}
                  >
                    Entra
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="btn"
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: '10px',
                      backgroundColor: '#5316d9',
                      color: 'white',
                    }}
                  >
                    Visita
                  </a>
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The problem is here:

```js
servers.database?.map((server, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="col">
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{
        width: '18rem',
        backgroundColor: '#101114',
        color: 'white',
        marginTop: '80px',
        borderRadius: '15px',
        boxShadow: '4px 3px 5px 0px #7335fb',
      }}
    >
      <img
        src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/843104500713127946/a_91371d39bec9e454d0f4ccacbfaea9f8.gif?size=512"
        className="card-img-top"
        alt="Icona server"
        style={{
          borderRadius: '50%',
          width: '96px',
          marginLeft: '20px',
          marginTop: '60px',
        }}
      />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{servers.bot[index].name || 'Errore!'}</h5>
        <br />
        <p className="card-text">{server.shortDescription}</p>
        <br />
        <a
          href="#"
          className="btn"
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#5316d9', color: 'white' }}
        >
          Entra
        </a>
        <a
          href="#"
          className="btn"
          style={{
            marginLeft: '10px',
            backgroundColor: '#5316d9',
            color: 'white',
          }}
        >
          Visita
        </a>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
));
```

Here the console output: 
[image: console output]

Someone know why it doesn't works? 
No error, all works fine, but he doesn't load array. 
VScode tell me that the initial `useState` value doesn't contain necessary data, but it arrive from database after, so I don't care. 
If you have any suggestion/solution, please tell me. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English!

Comment: Your API response does not have a `.database` property. Figure out what you want to render from the API response, and navigate the object accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your `console.log("servers object updated: " + JSON.stringify(servers));` log you'll see that it's an object without a `database` property.

From what I can see of the logged state, the render should use the `servers.servers` property array to map:

```
{servers.servers?.map((server, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="col">
    <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem", backgroundColor: "#101114", color: "white", marginTop: "80px", borderRadius: "15px", boxShadow: "4px 3px 5px 0px #7335fb" }}>
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/843104500713127946/a_91371d39bec9e454d0f4ccacbfaea9f8.gif?size=512" className="card-img-top" alt="Icona server" style={{ borderRadius: "50%", width: "96px", marginLeft: "20px", marginTop: "60px" }} />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{servers.bot[index].name || "Errore!"}</h5><br />
        <p className="card-text">{server.shortDescription}</p><br />
        <a href="#" className="btn" style={{ backgroundColor: "#5316d9", color: "white" }}>Entra</a>
        <a href="#" className="btn" style={{ marginLeft: "10px", backgroundColor: "#5316d9", color: "white" }}>Visita</a>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: @BlackdestinyXX Yes, sorry... took a look at the properties you were trying to access and took a closer look at the response in the image and noticed there was more than one array there.